# Как отфильтровать столбец с датами в Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Есть столбец Last, где n-ое количество дат в виде %d,%m,%Y за последние несколько лет. Нужно выбрать оттуда и вынести в отдельный дата фрейм только те даты, которые больше определенного значения. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных.  [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

сперва можно создать переменную, в которую по удовлетворяющему условию занесешь все значения.

```
f = df[df['Last'] > '25-04-04']
```

где 25-04-04 это определенное значение, больше которого у тебя должны быть даты. Однако есть небольшая оговорочка - код может не работать, если панда не знает, что это именно даты, поэтому изначально я бы перевел этот столбец в даты через

```
df['Last'] = pd.to_datetime('Last')
```

далее добавляешь в новый фрейм, либо сериес, как уж удобнее и смотря на то, что собираешься делать дальше

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=f, columns=['NewData'])
```